# :Ctags command returns "E492: Not an editor command: Ctags" error

Tags: filetype-ruby

I have vim-rails plugin installed (it's definitely installed as evidenced by good output from `:echo rails#app()`. I have ctags installed with: `brew install --with-jansson --HEAD universal-ctags/universal-ctags/universal-ctags`

When I run `:Ctags` in vim exec mode, I get the error: `:Ctags command returns "E492: Not an editor command: Ctags" error`. I have tried running this command from Gemfile and .rb files inside the rails app.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I had `packadd vim-rails` in an ftplugin/ruby.vim file. Apparently this causes problems. Placing directly in `~/.vimrc` file fixed the problem.